# How to find the max/min values using groupby with dates?

Tags: python, date, dataframe

Below is my dataframe. It has multiple stocks. I am trying to find out two things from this data.

1) How can I find the date with the min/max relative volatility for all the stocks. This means the maximum and minimum relative volatility for every stock with the corresponding date.

```
         Stock   Date              relativevolatility
0        AA.csv 2012-12-31            0.024419
1        AA.csv 2012-12-28            0.012888
2        AA.csv 2012-12-27            0.026482
3        AA.csv 2012-12-26            0.018423
4        AA.csv 2012-12-24            0.013994
5        AA.csv 2012-12-21            0.017422
6        AA.csv 2012-12-20            0.011541
7        AA.csv 2012-12-19            0.026316
8        AA.csv 2012-12-18            0.018120
9        AA.csv 2012-12-17            0.019406
10       AA.csv 2012-12-14            0.018454
11       AA.csv 2012-12-13            0.017411
12       AA.csv 2012-12-12            0.012673
13       AA.csv 2012-12-11            0.019699
14       AA.csv 2012-12-10            0.016442
15       AA.csv 2012-12-07            0.016403
16       AA.csv 2012-12-06            0.014011
17       AA.csv 2012-12-05            0.022340
18       AA.csv 2012-12-04            0.016677
19       AA.csv 2012-12-03            0.011862
20       AA.csv 2012-11-30            0.015458
21       AA.csv 2012-11-29            0.017794
22       AA.csv 2012-11-28            0.030102
23       AA.csv 2012-11-27            0.016888
24       AA.csv 2012-11-26            0.012019
25       AA.csv 2012-11-23            0.010791
26       AA.csv 2012-11-21            0.012092
27       AA.csv 2012-11-20            0.020544
28       AA.csv 2012-11-19            0.016857
29       AA.csv 2012-11-16            0.027044
        ...        ...                 ...
70666  ZION.csv 2012-02-15            0.018929
70667  ZION.csv 2012-02-14            0.016287
```

Attempt #1
df2.groupby(['Date','Stock'])['relativevolatility'].sum().idxmax()

This gives me a time/stock, but only for one stock and I am not sure i am even getting the maximum relative-volatility for that stock.

Attempt #2
new.groupby(['Stock'])['relativevolatility'].agg([pd.np.min, pd.np.max])

This gives me all the min/max's for the stocks, but I can't figure out how to add a column for when the min and max occurred for each stock.

## Question #1

How can I print a table that gives me all of the stock's min/max relative volatility with the dates for when the min/max occurred for the stocks?

## Question #2

How can find the average relative volatility, but for each day of the week for all the stocks?

Answer (score 1):

You need [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with
[`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
#if necessary
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('Stock')['relativevolatility'].idxmin()].set_index('Stock')
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('Stock')['relativevolatility'].idxmax()].set_index('Stock')

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=('min','max'))
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
           min_Date  min_relativevolatility   max_Date  max_relativevolatility
Stock                                                                         
AA.csv   2012-11-23                0.010791 2012-11-28                0.030102
ZION.csv 2012-02-14                0.016287 2012-02-15                0.018929
```

and [`weekday_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday_name.html) with aggregate `mean`:

```
df = (df.groupby(['Stock', df['Date'].dt.weekday_name])['relativevolatility']
        .mean()
        .reset_index(name='means'))
print (df)
      Stock       Date     means
0    AA.csv     Friday  0.016923
1    AA.csv     Monday  0.016428
2    AA.csv   Thursday  0.017448
3    AA.csv    Tuesday  0.018386
4    AA.csv  Wednesday  0.020324
5  ZION.csv    Tuesday  0.016287
6  ZION.csv  Wednesday  0.018929
```